# Show that this functional is coercive - variational methods

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

For $u \in H^{1}_0({\Omega})$ ($\Omega$  is a domain open and  bounded in $R^n$). Let $0 < \lambda < \lambda_1$ ($\lambda_1$ is the first eigen value of the laplacean)  and a fixed $f \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ define

$$ \varphi(u) = \displaystyle\int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2 + \lambda (\cos u -1) - fu \ dx$$

I am doing trying to show that $\varphi$ is coercive, that is $\varphi(u) \rightarrow \infty$ if $|| u||_{H^{1}_{0}}  \rightarrow \infty$. If i have this then a exercise that i am trying to do is done. But i am not seeing how to do this ... Someone can give me  a help to show this ?

Maybe the Poincare inequality helps $|| u||^{2}_{H^{1}_{0}} \geq \lambda_1 || u||^{2}_{L^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Poincaré is the place to begin. Don't use up all of the good stuff, though.  Stash an $\epsilon $ of it away: 
$$\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 \ge \epsilon \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 + (1-\epsilon)\lambda_1 \int_\Omega u^2$$
where $\epsilon $ is small enough so that $(1-\epsilon)\lambda_1\ge \lambda$.
 Then estimate 
$$1-\cos u  = 2\sin^2 \frac{u}{2} \le \frac{u^2}{2}$$
thus obtaining
$$
\varphi(u) \ge \frac{\epsilon }2 \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 - \int_{\Omega} fu
$$
 Here $fu$ contributes $O(\|u\|_{L^2})$ (linear term), which is dominated by the square of the Sobolev norm when the latter is large.